# NodeJS Koa: How to map a hostname to a htttps server

Tags: javascript, node.js, https, koa, koa2

I have created `https` server on port 3000 however, currently it is using IP in place of hostname (`app.example.com`). Hence all the requests happen at `https://12.34.56.78:3000`.

My current code:

```
let options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'certs/abc.key'), 'utf8').toString(),
  cert: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'certs/abc.crt'), 'utf8').toString(),
};

const httpsServer = https.createServer(options,app.callback())
  .listen(process.env.PORT, "0.0.0.0", listening)

function listening () {
  console.log("listening");
}
```

I want that all request to happen at `https://app.example.com:3000`.

How can I achieve this?

NOTE:

1. I have a registered hostname (for example `app.example.com`)
2. I have this hostname already running my html,css, and js static files on IIS
3. I want to use the same hostname for serving APIs of the same website. Hence same hostname

Comment: Well, you can't buy 'app.example.com', but I assume it's a placeholder. Find a domain registrar and setup DNS.

Comment: I have a hostname that is registered and DNS setup. And yes assume `app.example.com` is a placeholder.

Comment: So I have my static html,css,js also running on the same domain name `app.example.com` on IIS. I want to use the same hostname for serving APIs of the same website. Hence same hostname

Comment: If you want the exact same hostname for both, you will have to set up a reverse proxy to point to either site, based on for example the path.